# Azure Storage Queue data overhead with python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, wireshark, azure-storage-queues

I'm using wireshark to understand the data usage when posting messages to an azure storage queue via the python SDK (https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-queue/).

The wireshark capture filter has been set to show communication to and from the Azure queue. The following table shows the data transferred for a single post to the queue (certificate exchange has already occurred). If I post multiple messages using `queue.send_message`, the entire block repeats.

[image: Wireshark capture data]

The message itself is posted as part of line 2 (length 429 bytes, which varies with message size as expected). Then there is a TCP Ack and the response comes back (fixed length, 753 bytes), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-message.

I do not understand the first (619 bytes) or last (88 bytes) packets, which are also of fixed length even when varying message size. Any idea what these other packets are?

Comment: Interesting observation - how are you authenticating? Authentication via oauth can do a token request - however in that scenario I'd expect to see an additional response from the service...
Do you notice this behaviour with other Azure (Python) SDKs? Or have you only seen it when sending a queue message?